# How to delay code without freezing the app

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delay my code by 5 seconds this is what I'm using

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

However this freeze my app completly I wonder if there's a better way

Comment: Are you sure that is the line that is freezing the app?

Comment: In an async method you could do `await Task.Delay(5000);`

Comment: Read about [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Yes thread.Sleep put the tread to sleep and i don't want that @TerryTyson

Comment: it is because you freeze it. :)

Comment: If I may ask, why are you delaying your code? There may be alternatives to what you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that.

One of them is to create a new thread so the main thread will keep going when you freeze the new one.

```
using System.Threading;
Console.WriteLine("Hello from the main thread");
new Thread(() => 
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
    Console.WriteLine("Background thread started"); 
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Waited 5 sec"); 
}).Start();
Console.WriteLine("The main thread is still running while the other one is waiting");
```